# Mapping text data through huggingface tokenizer

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, huggingface-transformers

I have my encode function that looks like this:

```py
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertModel

MODEL = 'bert-base-multilingual-uncased'
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODEL)

def encode(texts, tokenizer=tokenizer, maxlen=10):
#     import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    inputs = tokenizer.encode_plus(
        texts,
        return_tensors='tf',
        return_attention_masks=True, 
        return_token_type_ids=True,
        pad_to_max_length=True,
        max_length=maxlen
    )

    return inputs['input_ids'], inputs["token_type_ids"], inputs["attention_mask"]
```

I want to get my data encoded on the fly by doing this:

```py
x_train = (tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(df_train.comment_text.astype(str).values)
           .map(encode))
```

However, this chucks the error:

```
ValueError: Input is not valid. Should be a string, a list/tuple of strings or a list/tuple of integers.
```

Now from my understanding when I set a breakpoint inside `encode` it was because I was sending a non-numpy array. How do I get huggingface transformers to play nice with tensorflow strings as inputs?

If you need a dummy dataframe here it is:

```
df_train = pd.DataFrame({'comment_text': ['Today was a good day']*5})
```

### What I tried

So I tried to use `from_generator` so that I can parse in the strings to the `encode_plus` function. However, this does not work with TPUs.

```py
AUTO = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE

def get_gen(df):
    def gen():
        for i in range(len(df)):
            yield encode(df.loc[i, 'comment_text']) , df.loc[i, 'toxic']
    return gen

shapes = ((tf.TensorShape([maxlen]), tf.TensorShape([maxlen]), tf.TensorShape([maxlen])), tf.TensorShape([]))

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    get_gen(df_train),
    ((tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32), tf.int32),
    shapes
)
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE).prefetch(AUTO)
```

### Version Info:

`transformers.__version__, tf.__version__` => `('2.7.0', '2.1.0')`

Comment: Please include the package versions of tensorflow and transformers.

Comment: @cronoik it was `'2.7.0', '2.1.0'`.

Comment: Are you sure? When I try it with your example data I get a different error message `ValueError: Input is not valid. Should be a string, a list/tuple of strings or a list/tuple of integers.` Which can be fixed easily, but your error message is different so it might not help you. Can you please test it again with your given example df_train?

Comment: Ugh, my bad must have copied some other error. @cronoik

Answer (score 6):

the tokenizer of bert works on a string, a list/tuple of strings or a list/tuple of integers. So, check is your data getting converted to string or not. To apply tokenizer on whole dataset I used Dataset.map, but this runs on graph mode. So, I need to wrap it in a tf.py_function. The tf.py_function will pass regular tensors (with a value and a .numpy() method to access it), to the wrapped python function. My data was getting converted to bytes after using py_function hence I applied tf.compat.as_str to convert bytes to string.

```
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
def encode(lang1, lang2):
    lang1 = tokenizer.encode(tf.compat.as_str(lang1.numpy()), add_special_tokens=True)
    lang2 = tokenizer.encode(tf.compat.as_str(lang2.numpy()), add_special_tokens=True)
    return lang1, lang2
def tf_encode(pt, en):
    result_pt, result_en = tf.py_function(func = encode, inp = [pt, en], Tout=[tf.int64, tf.int64])
    result_pt.set_shape([None])
    result_en.set_shape([None])
    return result_pt, result_en
train_dataset = dataset3.map(tf_encode)
BUFFER_SIZE = 200
BATCH_SIZE = 64

train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE).padded_batch(BATCH_SIZE, 
                                                           padded_shapes=(60, 60))
a,p = next(iter(train_dataset))
```

Comment: Amazing, your answer helped me a lot!

Comment: Please note that when using `tf.py_function`, you will not be able to save model using `model.save(...)` as the custom python code cannot be serialized into tensorflow format. I used this solution, but now I am looking for a workaround for saving the model.

Answer (score 2):

When you create the tensorflow dataset with: `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(df_train.comment_text.astype(str).values)`
tensorflow converts your strings into tensors of string type which is not an accepted input of of [tokenizer.encode_plus](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/tokenizer.html#transformers.PreTrainedTokenizer.encode_plus). Like the error message says it only accepts `a string, a list/tuple of strings or a list/tuple of integers`. You can verify this by adding a `print(type(texts))` inside your encode function (Output:`<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>`).

I'm not sure what your follow up plan is and why you need a `tf.data.Dataset`, but you have to encode your input before you turn it into a `tf.data.Dataset`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertModel

MODEL = 'bert-base-multilingual-uncased'
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODEL)

texts = ['Today was a good day', 'Today was a bad day',
       'Today was a rainy day', 'Today was a sunny day',
       'Today was a cloudy day']


#inputs['input_ids'], inputs["token_type_ids"], inputs["attention_mask"]
inputs = tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(
        texts,
        return_tensors='tf',
        return_attention_masks=True, 
        return_token_type_ids=True,
        pad_to_max_length=True,
        max_length=10
    )

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((inputs['input_ids'],
                                              inputs['attention_mask'],
                                              inputs['token_type_ids']))
print(type(dataset))
```

Output:

```
<class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.TensorSliceDataset'>
```

Comment: Wasn't entirely what I meant. I created a [feature request](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/4129) in the Huggingface repo. But I really appreciate you taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: So you are actually looking for a way to include the transformers tokenizer in the tensorflow execution graph (or whatever it is called)?

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact error but my mistake was simple, I had a few NaNs in my texts.

So make sure to check if there are NaNs in your texts dataframe.